# php border around table

Tags: html, css

I have a php script where the output is 2 rows of data. Is it possible to add a border around a table and its components(tr,td) in php? I would like to add the border with CSS in the style element.

**This is my code:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
td {
border-style: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>oef2</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
$host = "localhost";
$user = "*******";
$password = "*******";
$database = "elektrowinkel";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password) or die("Er kan geen connectie gelegd worden met $host");

mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die("databank $database niet beschikbaar");

$query = "SELECT * FROM stock_magazijnen";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query) or die("Er is een fout opgetreden bij het uitvoeren van de query: \"$query\"");

$aantalRecords = mysqli_num_rows($result);

echo("<table><tr><th>Magazijn_ID</th><th>Product_ID</th><th>Aantal</th></tr>");

while($rij = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo("<tr>
                <td>".$rij['Magazijn_ID']."</td>
                <td>".$rij['Product_ID']."</td>
                <td>".$rij['Aantal']."</td>
        </tr> ");
}
echo("</table>");

mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: How? I can't find an example...

Comment: just change `border-style` to `border`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have just the `<td>`'s to have a border, do (while changing border-style to border):

```
<style>
td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

If you want the entire table and `<td>`'s to have a border, then add `table` in the declaration

```
<style>
table, td {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

If you want just a border around the table but not the `<td>`

```
<style>
table {
border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table style="border: 10px solid black">.....</table>
```